# Bourne Shell: Convert ~/Desktop to /users/me/Desktop

Tags: bash, scripting, path

The keytool does not resolve impartial directories.  Ie this works:

```
keytool -keystore "/users/me/Desktop" ...
```

This doesn't:

```
keytool -keystore "~/Desktop" ...
```

Is there something that I could call like this:

```
keytool -keystore "$(<cmd> ~/Desktop)" ...
```

#### Update

I guess I should actually be more specific:

This is really what I am doing:

```
myVar=~/Desktop
<allow user to overwrite default value of myVar>
keytool -keystore "$myVar" ...
```

I don't think that it is safe to have $myVar unquoted in the keytool command in case someone puts some malicious code in there.

Comment: As cute as that is, the tags are disorganized enough as they are. Please don't create new ones that aren't needed.

Comment: based on your edit, you definitely want eval as the shell doesn't expand things recursively. Meaning it will expand the variable but not what is inside the variable

Comment: You should use `$HOME` or parse `/etc/passwd` (e.g. using `getent`) or similar authentication file/service. I think `~` is intended more as a command-line convenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about

```
keytool -keystore "$(echo ~/Desktop)"
```

or

```
keytool -keystore "$HOME/Desktop"
```

But, on the other hand, ~/Desktop should work fine as well. Tried with bash only, don't have any other Bourne shells here.

Answer (score 4):

That's because you are quoting the path. Keytool, or any other command line program in unix is agnostic of the wildrcards, because the shell is used to actually expanding the path names. If you don't quote the path, it'll work peachy.

Comment: I don't know anything about keytool, but i'd say that is not necessarily true based on the existence of $@.

Comment: Double quotes should be fine. Single quotes will treat it as a literal string.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is a programming question, but did you try it without the quotes? i.e.

```
keytool -keystore ~/Desktop ...
```

Answer (score 1):

eval echo "~/foo"

e.g. keytool -keystore $(eval echo ~/Desktop)

Comment: works for me. Are you sure you don't have your close quotes reverse as you do in what you put in the comment?